# Парсинг txt файла посторочно, поиск и выдача результата

Tags: php, text, парсер

Необходимо разместить кнопку поиска запчастей на сайте, файл с запчастями находиться в корне сайта и имеет следующий вид:

ford.txt

```
0000006|4,46
0000323|3,25
0010214|277,52
0010636|683,46
0010699|305,88
0012104|305,88
0012172|0,41
0012173|0,41
0020847|608,51
...
```

вводим окно поиска номер запчасти (к примеру: 0000006) ниже выводится результат поиска (стоимость запчасти): 4,46 руб.

А если я хочу сделать вывод в виде таблицы, соответственно, добавляю в файле следующее:

```
0000006|4,46|2N11-15201-AB|Хомут
0000323|3,25
0010214|277,52
0010636|683,46
0010699|305,88
0012104|305,88
0012172|0,41
0012173|0,41
0020847|608,51
...
```

нажимаем на кнопку поиск, выводится таблица со следующим содержанием:

```
FINIS: 0000006 Инженерный номер: 2N11-15201-AB Описание: Хомут. Цена: 4,46 руб.
```

Как интегрировать данный код на сайт?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
$search      = "0000006";
$result = false;

if ($handle = fopen("ford.txt", "r")) {
    $count = 0;
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== FALSE) {
        $line = explode('|', $line);
        if($line && $line[0] == $search){
            $result = $line;
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

var_dump($result);
```

Думаю с массивом разберетесь что делать. А в остальном, вам стоит самому попробовать найти решение, или отобразить ваши попытки что бы мы могли понимать что вы пытаетесь сделать. Так же, возможно, вам стоит подумать над тем что бы не искать в файле а заливать файл в базу или какую либо поисковый движок и осуществлять поиск там.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <?
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
define('COLUMN_SEPARATOR', '|');
$fileName = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'ford.txt';

if ($_REQUEST['search']) {
    $arResult = false;
    $firstLine = true;
    $handle = @fopen($fileName, "r");
    if ($handle) {
        while (($arItem = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, COLUMN_SEPARATOR)) !== false) {
            // fix file UTF-8 BOM
            if ($firstLine) {
                $arItem[0] = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $arItem[0]); 
                $firstLine = false;
            }

            if ($arItem[0] == $_REQUEST['number']) {
                $arResult = $arItem;
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            table { border-collapse: collapse; } 
            td { border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px; }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" name="number" value="" />
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Найти" />
    </form>
    <? if (isset($arResult)): ?>
        <? if (!$arResult): ?>
            Ничего не найдено
        <? elseif (count($arResult) <= 2): ?>
            Cтоимость запчасти: <?=$arResult[1]?> руб.
        <? else: ?>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>FINIS: <?=$arResult[0]?></td>
                    <td>Инженерный номер: <?=$arResult[2]?></td>
                    <td>Описание: <?=$arResult[3]?></td>
                    <td>Цена: <?=$arResult[1]?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <? endif ?>
    <? endif ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что это? Ответ или дополнение к вопросу? Если дополнение, то внесите его в свой вопрос нажав ссылку **править** под вопросом, а этот сообщение удалите.